# Can I make this workflow faster? Rollup watch / npm live-server

Tags: rollup, rollupjs, npm-live-server

I'm trying to achieve a 'live' workflow for a website i'm about to build.

It's based on [this boilerplate](https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm).

I currently have this workflow working:

Write code -> Save -> 'Rollup watch' rebuilds build/main.js from src/main.js -> 'live-server' refreshes browser.

I'm new to a lot of this, so i'll be honest and say that the **8s it takes per build** is a hell of a lot faster than my old workflow, which involved manual fileZilla and a noobier me developing on a password protected subdomain.

Is there a way I should be doing this so that I'm not waiting for the builds to happen - it seems unnecessary? E.g. use a dummy index.html that temporarily links to the src/main.js until i'm ready to build and deploy the bundled version on to my domain?

This is the current index.html of the boilerplate:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Example for Three JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="homepage"></div>

    <script src='build/main.js'></script>

    <script>
        const app = new LIB.App;
        app.init();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is what my rollup config file looks like:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'; // locate and bundle dependencies in node_modules (mandatory)
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser"; // code minification (optional)

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: [
        {
            format: 'umd',
            name: 'LIB',
            file: 'build/main.js'
        }
    ],
    plugins: [ resolve(), terser() ]
};
```

I tried just switching out the script source from

```
<script src='build/main.js'></script>
```

to

```
<script src='src/main.js'></script>
```

and removing:

```
<script>
    const app = new LIB.App;
    app.init();
</script>
```

But this didn't work - so i'm here looking for input.

Answer (score 3):

The 'answer' is that I should have been using a dev and prod version of my rollup builds. The dev version should have minification removed.

From [Documentation](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#using-config-files):

You can, if you like, specify a different config file from the default `rollup.config.js`:

```
rollup --config rollup.config.dev.js
rollup --config rollup.config.prod.js
```